# Draw angle between axis and line using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

i tried to draw a angle between a line, and the X axis using pgfplots, i saw a lot of ways using tikz and other packages but, there is any way to do this using pgfplots?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzfigure}
    \begin{axis}[
            axis x line = center,
            axis y line = center,
            xlabel = $x$,
            ylabel = $y$,
              xmin=-1.0,
              xmax=3.0,
              ymin=-1.0,
              ymax=3.0,
          disabledatascaling,
          axis equal,
        ]
    \addplot [->, color=blue] coordinates {(0, 0) (2, 3)};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzfigure}
\end{document}
```

What can i write to get an angle like this?
[image: angle]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not directly, but I also do not see a need for that. But of course you can just define 3 coordinates and then use the `angles` library to draw angles were needed.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.17
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        angles,
        quotes,
    }
    % use this `compat` level or higher so TikZ coordinates
    % are in axis units by default
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=center,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        xmin=-1.0,
        xmax=3.0,
        ymin=-1.0,
        ymax=3.0,
        disabledatascaling,
        axis equal,
    ]
        \coordinate (xaxis) at (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);
        \coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
        \addplot [->,blue] coordinates {(0, 0) (2, 3)}
            coordinate [at end] (A)
        ;
        \path (xaxis) -- (origin) -- (A)
            pic [
                draw,
                ->,
                red,
                angle radius=10mm,
                angle eccentricity=1.2,
                "$\theta$",
            ] {angle = xaxis--origin--A}
        ;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]